# How do you toggle inlay hints?

Tags: neovim, lua, lsp

Previously, `vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable()` used to toggle inlay hints. However, this functionality has been removed and now `vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable()` just enables inlay hints. How can I toggle inlay hints like I used to?

Comment: Would love for whomever downvoted to explain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/26679#issuecomment-1864538947)

```lua
lsp.inlay_hint.enable(0, not lsp.inlay_hint.is_enabled())
```

It seems moving forward the lua api will not include implicit toggling, or a `.toggle()` functionality.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I took it out on your suggestion